# Jenkins stuck on console output while building android app

Tags: android, jenkins

I am beginner into jenkins build enviorment , i am basically trying to build android hello work app with jenkins .

Everytime i build the android-app the console out is stuck and never ends and nor its listing any error am not able to understand why it takes more than 1 hour to build or what is not added to build enviornmnet properly .

Below is the screenshot for the same  :

[image]

I had configure the jenkins gobal properties like jdk, Android_home path etc.

My Config :

[image]

My Project setting :

[image]

Comment: Are you getting any error message anywhere?
Please provide the exact command your job is running + any additional steps performed, and any additional log of the run if you have it.

Comment: can you please tell me where i could find any additional log since i only know console output is logging the progress.

Comment: The last line in the screenshot indicates a log file - might work checking if it contains something of interest

Comment: yup i checked that its always 0kb file

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your job config and steps?

Comment: i had just posted the steps which i had filled , not complete page screenshot plz refer i had follow above screenshot steps

Comment: Looks like Jenkins is trying to install JDK 1.7.
Can you verify its set correctly on Jenkins? Manage Jenkins > Configure System > JDK > JDK Installations... > Verify it points to correct JDK and JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the "Install automatically" checkbox.
You do not need the job to install JDK for you. Install it manually, and then point to it on the config.
Once you remove the check box you will be able to point to JDK version and JAVA_HOME.
Like so:

[image]